# Rails app make 2 actions per 1 request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

my problem: I have a rails app, now i see at logs on production and dev different computers, that something double all actions:

routes:

```
  root "main_page#index"
  resources :search, only: [:index]
```

logs heroku (production)

```
2014-02-10T07:45:08.214686+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/search?type=shortdata
&data=501" for 1.1.1.1 at 2014-02-10 07:45:08 +0000
2014-02-10T07:45:08.214734+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/search?type=shortdata
&data=501" for 1.1.1.1 at 2014-02-10 07:45:08 +0000
2014-02-10T07:45:08.222497+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/search
?type=shortdata&data=501 host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=4a0c2345-336
e-44fd-b33b-44caeb3bac90 fwd="1.1.1.1" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13m
s status=304 bytes=0
2014-02-10T07:45:08.217106+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SearchController#inde
x as JSON
2014-02-10T07:45:08.217106+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SearchController#inde
x as JSON
2014-02-10T07:45:08.217106+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"type"=>"shortdata",
 "data"=>"501"}
2014-02-10T07:45:08.217106+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"type"=>"shortdata",
 "data"=>"501"}
2014-02-10T07:45:08.222806+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.5
ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
2014-02-10T07:45:08.222806+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 0.5
ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
```

controller:

```
def index
    data = params[:data]
    type=params[:type]
    if type==ShortDataType
      if likeAZip?(data)
        render(json:shortSearchByZip(data)) && return
      else
        render(json:shortSearchByCity(data)) && return
      end
    else
    render json:nothing
    end
  end
```

no callbacks, set (puts 1 after "def index") - it go to logs only 1 times - result:

```
Started GET "/search?type=shortdata&data=501" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-10 18:54:
38 +1100
Started GET "/search?type=shortdata&data=501" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-10 18:54:
38 +1100
Processing by SearchController#index as JSON
Processing by SearchController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"type"=>"shortdata", "data"=>"501"}
  Parameters: {"type"=>"shortdata", "data"=>"501"}
1
   (2.0ms)  select .....
```

what is it?

Comment: can you add your html.erb file and your javascript if your search is done via ajax ? I think I had a similar problem in the past and it was not due to server code but it was on browser side.

Comment: I have seen things like this when Ajax calls where linked to events like onchange. Those sometimes fire more often than you may think.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in gem **rails_12factor**

That was included in all ENV, and it made double logging.
Actions really make only once

Now I add **group: :production** to gem, and plan to change webrick web server to other in prod

thanks for the help